# Deep copy of object with C array

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, arrays, deep-copy

I have an object with a 2d C array (can't figure out how to do the same with NSArray) and I also need this object to provide deep copies of itself. I'm trying to implement the NSCopying protocol except when trying to make a copy of the c array i can't figure out how to reference self's array and the copy's array. Since it's not a property and obj c doesn't support c array properties as far as i know, i don't know how to set the new copy's array.

I've tried typedefing my array as a struct but I'm also using ARC so that isn't a valid solution

Hopefully I'm not missing something basic. Thanks.

Comment: Post what you have so people can help you with the code.

Comment: since you mentioned the 2D NSArray quest, ["How to create a 2D NSArray or NSMutableArray in Objective C"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261329/how-to-create-a-2d-nsarray-or-nsmutablearray-in-objective-c)

Comment: Hi WhozCraig. My outer array can contain many inner arrays so I'd prefer to use a more elegant solution than having to init each array in a loop. But if i can't I'll probably settle on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `->` notation to access the instance variables of the copied object.  When making a deep copy, each object in the array must be copied.

```
// define a custom class to store in the array
@interface OtherClass : NSObject <NSCopying>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *string;
@end

@implementation OtherClass
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    OtherClass *temp = [OtherClass new];
    temp.string = [self.string stringByAppendingString:@" (copy)"];
    return( temp );
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog( @"OtherClass dealloc: %@", self.string );
}
@end

// define the class that contains a C array of custom objects
@interface SomeClass : NSObject <NSCopying>
{
    OtherClass *array[5][5];
}
@end

@implementation SomeClass
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    SomeClass *temp = [SomeClass new];

    for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
        for ( int j = 0; j < 5; j++ )
            temp->array[i][j] = [array[i][j] copy];

    return( temp );
}

- (void)storeObject:(OtherClass *)object atRow:(int)row Col:(int)col
{
    array[row][col] = object;
    object.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"row:%d col:%d", row, col];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog( @"SomeClass dealloc" );
}
@end

// test code to create, copy, and destroy the objects
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    SomeClass *a = [SomeClass new];

    for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
        for ( int j = 0; j < 5; j++ )
            [a storeObject:[OtherClass new] atRow:i Col:j];

    SomeClass *b = [a copy];

    NSLog( @"Releasing A" );
    a = nil;

    NSLog( @"Releasing B" );
    b = nil;
}
```

Comment: Looks good, just want to ask are there any additional memory management issues I should be aware of?

Comment: I don't believe so.  AFAIK, the instance variables are dealloc'd when the object itself is dealloc'd.  Of course, if you `malloc` items to put in the array, then you must override the `dealloc` method to `free` those items.

Comment: @K.He I guess I should ask, "What you are storing in the array?"

Comment: I'm storing a custom subclass of NSObject. Also does memcpy allocate separate memory from the original array?

Comment: ok, I was thinking that you were storing primitives. I will update the sample code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer definitely let me make some significant progress.